# web service (bpel) and unstructured data combination

Tags: node.js, mongodb, bpel

I have a dilemma. My existing transactional system (behind bpel) is web service based (xml data transport) and for some new features such as mobile apps I need to use legacy web services and innovative solutions such as node+mongo to store unstructured data and files.
  My question is should I use bpel front end for both mongo and legacy system so that my mobile app has only one end point to talk to. If so there is a problem of two data format handling (xml and json).
  OR
 Should my mobile client talk to both thus have two end points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that BPEL uses SOAP protocol which supports only XML. I have used Oracle BPEL 11g. I am not sure about other BPEL products from other companies.

If it is RESTFul service, then a web service endpoint can produce the response in different formats (such as XML, JSON etc.) based on the ACCEPT attribute in HTTP header.

If the consuming application/service set the acceptable format (i.e. ACCEPT attribute) in HTTP header, then the web service can produce the response in that format.

If the web service is unable to produce response in the acceptable format, it should throw "HTTP 406 error".

Comment: i tried , it did not work , i am still getting xml as response. not sure if i missed any thing. I did exactly like http://www.soawork.com/2014/01/create-restful-webservice-in-soa.html and set Accept:application/json in request header.

Comment: The above solution is a generic way to produce the response (in REST API) in different formats based on the client request. In terms of oracle 11g bpm tool specifically, please check in the response setting whether there is an option to specify the response format. Refer this link https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/oracle-soa-bpel-11g-spring-support-enable-rest-json-capability-deep